# Does LinqDataSource perform Server-Side paging by default?

Tags: linq, paging, server-side

I've seen hints around the net that this is the case, but I can't find any official documentation to this effect. I want to be sure I have my facts straight before I utilize the LinqDataSource.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`LinqDataSource.AutoPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.autopage.aspx). You can set this using the following:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource 
    .
    .
    .
    AutoPage="true"
    .
    .
    .
    runat="server">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Note that, from the documentation, this property is `true` by default:

> `true` if the user can page through the data; otherwise, `false`. The default value is `true`.

Further:

> When the `AutoPage` property is set to `true`, the `LinqDataSource` control retrieves only enough records for one page in the data-bound control. It uses the `Skip(TSource)` and `Take(TSource)` methods to retrieve the records for the current page.

Comment: Setting it to true will enable server-side paging, then?

Comment: Yes, and the default value is `true`.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this plays nice with the Where property in the configuration designer for this datasource? It would be unfortunate for it to return one page of results, then filter them to nothing because none met the filter criteria. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand your question to mean: if you use a `Where` (`<asp:LinqDataSource ... Where="some predicate" ... runat="server"></asp:LinqDataSource>`) is the filtering done on the server and then pages of the results returned? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using sql profiler to test the performance of your sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not perform it by default, however it is very easy to implement with

```
.Skip(perPage*(page-1)).Take(perPage)
```

edit: Huh, i guess it actually does!